# topology on polynomial spaces

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $E$ be a Banach space,and $P(E)$ be polynomial space.
Is there a topology on $P(E)$ which is equivalent with 
uniform topology?

Comment: What is a polynomial space?

Comment: And what is the uniform topology on $P(E)$?